# FFMPEG commands-strict experimental, -ar, -s, -b:a vs -ab, -b vs -b:v

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

What is the difference between below ffmpeg commands or are they same?

```
-b:a vs -ab
-b vs -b:v
```

AFAIK first row commands used for audio bit rate and second row commands for video bitrate

Also I am not able to understand what below commands do?

```
-strict experimental
-ar
```

(example: `-ar 22050`)

```
-s
```

(example: `-s 160x120`)

Answer (score 2):

Consult the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

`-b:a`, `-ab` both set the bitrate for any audio streams being encoded. Have no effect if audio is copied.

`-b:v` sets video bitrate, if video is being encoded. `-b` also sets video bitrate but should be avoided.

`-ar` sets the sampling rate for audio streams if encoded.

Some features are not up to grade or are not spec-compliant so ffmpeg will not allow their use unless overridden. `-strict experimental` or `-strict -2` does that. You may most commonly have seen this with the use of the native AAC encoder `-c:a aac`. But this option is not needed to use that if your build is newer than Dec 2015.

Comment: is -strict experimental needed if i am using ffmpeg version v0.3.2 and i am creating build now?

Comment: Yes. Don't use such an old version!.

Comment: I am using ffmpeg library by WritingMinds..https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java ..do I need to use strict experimental  with it?also does -s stands for screen size? Couldn't find in doc

Comment: Yes, `-s` stands for video output size. 0.3.2 is not the ffmpeg version but the version of the wrapper library you're using. FFmpeg build is from April 2016, so `-strict` shouldn't be needed.